Web page opened by WebAuthProvider.login on Android returns old Credentials
I use this code to give a user opportunity to log in on a webview using the following code:
val auth0 = Auth0(AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_DOMAIN)
WebAuthProvider.login(auth0)
    .withRedirectUri(AUTH0_REDIRECT_URL)
    .withScheme(AUTH0_SCHEME)
    .withScope(AUTH0_SCOPE)
    .start(
        context,
        object : Callback<Credentials, AuthenticationException> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: Credentials) {
                cont.resume(result)
            }

            override fun onFailure(error: AuthenticationException) {
                 cont.resumeWithException(error)
            }
        }
    )

and it works. But after a user enters wrong credentials, an error is shown and when a user clicks a button to try again, this code is invoked again, and it opens the webview just for a moment and the method returns old Credentials object. So there is no way to enter correct credentials for a user, the page is closed automatically too fast. It seems like some cookies are saved automatically or something like this. Is it possible to fix this issue?
